# Validating the Performance test aggregate report

Tags: web-applications, jmeter, performance-testing

I have jMeter based performance tests, i.e concurrent user load based results.
At the end of the test, Jmeter provides aggregate report, where we can see Avg response time, throughput etc etc. these are fine.

I want to validate these results and get a confidence that the test that I have performed is correct in terms of the configuration i have done like the number of users configured, ramp up time  etc.(From the application side, i can confirm that the transactions are actually working, i can trust the jMeter assertions etc, thats not am looking here)..

I see a great article about applying [Little's Law](http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-performance-testing-application-of-littles-law-to-workload-models/) in validating the result.
But I beleiev its about a stable system in terms of number of users appearing to the server in a steady pattern and maintaining the same load through out the system etc. (please correct me if am wrong here)

but in general, the user concurrency tests would be designed in such a way that the load changes like a stepping pattern as seen in below pic. 
[image]

In this situation is Little's Law still applicable ?
Or there any better mechanisim to validate the result and get confidence on the test performed and results not due to bottlenecks imposed by the testing apparatus.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absolute majority of cases Little's Law is being applied for [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) when you need to come up with a [workload pattern](https://qainsights.com/how-to-design-workload-model-for-load-testing/) standing for anticipated system usage.

For the other testing types like [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) or [Spike Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Spike_testing) sticking to the Little's Law doesn't make a lot of sense as workload differs.

With regards to results validation, my expectation is that the business is interested in the answers to the following questions:

1. Is the system capable of handling the anticipated load (load testing)
2. What is the maximum number of concurrent users which the system can support providing acceptable response time without errors (stress testing).
3. Does the system recover when the load gets back to normal
4. How does system handles sudden concurrent requests (Spike Testing)
5. Is the system capable of handling the load for long period of time ([Soak testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing))

Check out [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) article for more information on different performance testing subtypes which you might want to apply to your application.